# PHP: preg_match won't work correct

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I try to validate the registration form for the website. Unfortunately, no matter where I use a wrong entry it shows me the first statusbox:

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){  
    $freshpw = generate_pw();
    $mdpassword = md5($freshpw);
    $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$_POST['month'],$_POST['day'],$_POST['year']);
    $reggebdatum = date("d.m.Y",$timestamp);
    if (empty($_POST['regusername']) ||  check_username($_POST['regusername'])){
        statusbox("Username is given!", 0);
        echo "<div class='sections'>
              </div></div>";
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("refresh:1;url=index.php?act=register");
    }

else if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST['regname']) === 0){
         statusbox("Name can only contains letters spaces and dashes!",0);
        echo "<div class='sections'>
              </div></div>";
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("refresh:1;url=index.php?act=register");
        }


        else if(preg_match("/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST['regstreet']) === 0){
                 statusbox("Street can only contains letters spaces and dashes!",0);

        echo "<div class='sections'>
              </div></div>";
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("refresh:1;url=index.php?act=register");
        }
...
```

If I test it and write sth. on purpose wrong, like street or Zip it always shows me the error from name: **Name can only contains letters spaces and dashes**

Do I sth. wrong??

Comment: What do you test it against? You know it has to start with a Capital letter? And why do `preg_match(...) === 0` when you should do `!preg_match(...)` as it may be `0` or `false` in case of error.

Comment: What do you mean with: "..it has to start with a Capital letter?" ? Where exactly?

When i use !preg_match(...) instead of  === 0 won't it mean that i need to change the inside of the preg match(reversing everything)? Don't know exactly what you mean :/

Comment: `^[A-Z]` this means start with Capital letter: `A-Z`. `if(!preg_match())...` means `if(does not match(pattern))...`. So it's the error handling part. For success testing you do `if(preg_match())...`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much, that was the mistake(the starting Capital letter). Now it works. I would vote your answer up, but it's just a comment :)

Comment: Added it as an answer :) I'm such a score w***e...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You know it has to start with a Capital letter?** `^[A-Z]` this means start with Capital letter: `A-Z`.

And why do `preg_match(...) === 0` when you should do `!preg_match(...)` as it may be `0` or `false` in case of error. `if(!preg_match())...` means `if(does not match(pattern) or pattern is broken)...` So it's the error handling part. For success testing you do `if(preg_match())...`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will have it in mind for the next time. I'll try the !preg_match(...) the next days.